# How to remove searchbar from gnome activites overview?

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, debian-bookworm

This is one of those things that are pobably really easy, but you still can't figure it out.

I am not a fan of the regular applications menu in gnome, so I got the Arc Menu extention and removed the normal menu icon using the dash to dock extention. The problem I have is that Arc Menu has its own search bar, so I need to remove the search bar in the activities overview.

**Summary**: I want to remove the search bar you see in this screenshot
[image]

I am using gnome 43.9 by the way.